# TSQL - Reduce the number of records with intelligence - patterns (crash impact data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, azure

I have some data that contains data from measurements from crash impact tests.
When the object is not moving the measurements contain much rows of the same data, when the object is moving and shaking it can register quite big fluctuations.

Problem: I have **hundreds of millions** of lines of this data and to use it in reporting (mostly plotting) I have to find a way to make simplify everything and especially reduce the number of records.
Sometimes I have 20 times exactly the same value (=ChannelValue)

An example of the data is the following:

```css
idMetaData;TimeStamp;SampleNumber;ChannelValue
3;0,5036500;12073;0.4573468975
3;0,5037000;12074;0.4418814526
3;0,5037500;12075;0.4109505628
3;0,5038000;12076;0.4109505628
3;0,5038500;12077;0.4264160077
3;0,5038999;12078;0.4573468975
3;0,5039499;12079;0.4573468975
3;0,5039999;12080;0.4109505628
3;0,5040500;12081;0.3336233382
3;0,5041000;12082;0.2408306686
3;0,5041500;12083;0.1789688889
3;0,5042000;12084;0.1789688889
3;0,5042500;12085;0.2253652237
3;0,5042999;12086;0.3026924483
3;0,5043499;12087;0.3645542280
3;0,5044000;12088;0.3954851178
3;0,5044500;12089;0.3645542280
3;0,5045000;12090;0.3026924483
3;0,5045500;12091;0.2253652237
3;0,5046000;12092;0.1635034440
3;0,5046499;12093;0.1325725541
3;0,5046999;12094;0.1480379991
3;0,5047500;12095;0.1789688889
3;0,5048000;12096;0.1944343338
3;0,5048500;12097;0.2098997788
3;0,5049000;12098;0.1944343338
3;0,5049500;12099;0.1635034440
3;0,5049999;12100;0.1171071092
3;0,5050499;12101;0.0861762194
3;0,5051000;12102;0.0707107744
3;0,5051500;12103;0.0707107744
3;0,5052000;12104;0.0861762194
3;0,5052500;12105;0.1171071092
3;0,5053000;12106;0.1635034440
   
idMetaData;TimeStamp;SampleNumber;ChannelValue
50;0,8799999;19600;-0.7106432894
50;0,8800499;19601;-0.7484265845
50;0,8801000;19602;-0.7232377211
50;0,8801500;19603;-0.6098878356
50;0,8802000;19604;-0.6098878356
50;0,8802500;19605;-0.6476711307
50;0,8802999;19606;-0.7232377211
50;0,8803499;19607;-0.7988043114
50;0,8803999;19608;-0.8617764701
50;0,8804500;19609;-0.8491820384
50;0,8805000;19610;-0.8617764701
50;0,8805500;19611;-0.7988043114
50;0,8806000;19612;-0.8239931749
50;0,8806499;19613;-0.7988043114
50;0,8806999;19614;-0.7736154480
50;0,8807499;19615;-0.6602655625
50;0,8807999;19616;-0.5972934038
50;0,8808500;19617;-0.6602655625
50;0,8809000;19618;-0.7484265845
50;0,8809500;19619;-0.8365876066
50;0,8809999;19620;-0.7862098797
50;0,8810499;19621;-0.8113987432
50;0,8810999;19622;-0.7988043114
50;0,8811499;19623;-0.6980488576
50;0,8812000;19624;-0.7232377211
50;0,8812500;19625;-0.7484265845
50;0,8813000;19626;-0.7232377211
50;0,8813500;19627;-0.8239931749
50;0,8813999;19628;-0.8491820384
50;0,8814499;19629;-0.8617764701
50;0,8814999;19630;-0.8365876066
50;0,8815500;19631;-0.8365876066
50;0,8816000;19632;-0.7988043114
50;0,8816500;19633;-0.8113987432
50;0,8817000;19634;-0.8113987432
50;0,8817499;19635;-0.7736154480
50;0,8817999;19636;-0.7232377211
50;0,8818499;19637;-0.6728599942
50;0,8819000;19638;-0.7232377211
50;0,8819500;19639;-0.7610210163
50;0,8820000;19640;-0.7106432894
50;0,8820500;19641;-0.6602655625
50;0,8820999;19642;-0.6602655625
50;0,8821499;19643;-0.6854544259
50;0,8821999;19644;-0.7736154480
50;0,8822500;19645;-0.8113987432
50;0,8823000;19646;-0.8869653335
50;0,8823500;19647;-0.8743709018
50;0,8824000;19648;-0.7988043114
50;0,8824499;19649;-0.8491820384
50;0,8824999;19650;-0.8239931749
50;0,8825499;19651;-0.8239931749
50;0,8825999;19652;-0.7232377211
50;0,8826500;19653;-0.6854544259
50;0,8827000;19654;-0.6728599942
50;0,8827500;19655;-0.6854544259
50;0,8827999;19656;-0.7232377211
50;0,8828499;19657;-0.7232377211
50;0,8828999;19658;-0.6980488576
50;0,8829499;19659;-0.6980488576
50;0,8830000;19660;-0.7106432894
50;0,8830500;19661;-0.6854544259
50;0,8831000;19662;-0.7484265845
50;0,8831499;19663;-0.7484265845
50;0,8831999;19664;-0.7736154480
50;0,8832499;19665;-0.7610210163
50;0,8832999;19666;-0.7610210163
50;0,8833500;19667;-0.7988043114
50;0,8834000;19668;-0.8617764701
50;0,8834500;19669;-0.9121541970
50;0,8835000;19670;-0.8869653335
50;0,8835499;19671;-0.8743709018
50;0,8835999;19672;-0.9121541970
50;0,8836499;19673;-0.8491820384
50;0,8837000;19674;-0.7988043114
50;0,8837500;19675;-0.7736154480
50;0,8838000;19676;-0.7106432894
50;0,8838500;19677;-0.6980488576
50;0,8838999;19678;-0.7484265845
50;0,8839499;19679;-0.8491820384
50;0,8839999;19680;-0.8491820384
50;0,8840500;19681;-0.7610210163
50;0,8841000;19682;-0.7106432894
50;0,8841500;19683;-0.7232377211
50;0,8842000;19684;-0.7962098797
50;0,8842499;19685;-0.7358321528
50;0,8842999;19686;-0.7232377211
50;0,8843499;19687;-0.7484265845
50;0,8844000;19688;-0.6728599942
50;0,8844500;19689;-0.6854544259
50;0,8845000;19690;-0.7106432894
50;0,8845500;19691;-0.7232377211
50;0,8845999;19692;-0.7862098797
50;0,8846499;19693;-0.7862098797

idMetaData;TimeStamp;SampleNumber;ChannelValue
15;0,3148000;8296;1.5081626404
15;0,3148500;8297;1.5081626404
15;0,3149000;8298;1.5727382554
15;0,3149500;8299;1.5081626404
15;0,3150000;8300;1.4920187367
15;0,3150500;8301;1.4435870254
15;0,3151000;8302;1.4274431217
15;0,3151500;8303;1.5243065442
15;0,3152000;8304;1.4920187367
15;0,3152500;8305;1.5081626404
15;0,3153000;8306;1.4920187367
15;0,3153500;8307;1.5565943516
15;0,3154000;8308;1.5081626404
15;0,3154500;8309;1.5404504479
15;0,3155000;8310;1.5081626404
15;0,3155500;8311;1.5727382554
15;0,3156000;8312;1.5404504479
15;0,3156500;8313;1.3951553142
15;0,3157000;8314;1.4758748329
15;0,3157500;8315;1.4435870254
15;0,3158000;8316;1.4920187367
15;0,3158500;8317;1.4920187367
15;0,3159000;8318;1.5081626404
15;0,3159500;8319;1.4597309292
15;0,3160000;8320;1.4274431217
15;0,3160500;8321;1.4274431217
15;0,3161000;8322;1.4597309292
15;0,3161500;8323;1.5565943516
15;0,3162000;8324;1.5888821591
15;0,3162500;8325;1.5565943516
15;0,3163000;8326;1.5243065442
15;0,3163500;8327;1.5404504479
15;0,3164000;8328;1.5404504479
15;0,3164500;8329;1.5404504479
15;0,3165000;8330;1.5404504479
```

I want to reduce the number of records by factor 10 or 20.

One solution would be to keep the average of 20 rows but then there is one problem, when there is a peek it will 'evaporate' in the average.

What I'd need is an average of 20 rows ('ChannelValue') but when there is a value that is a 'peek' -> definition: differs more than 10% -positive or negative- with the last (2?) value(s) than for this one do not take the average but the peek value, and from there continue the averages... This is the **intelligence** I mean in the title
I could also use some sort of 'distinct' logic that will also reduce the number of records by factor 8 to 10.

I read stuff about the NTILE function but this is all new for me.

Partition by idMetadata, order by id (there is an id column which I did not include right now)

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: can you edit your data to show what values belong to what columns

Comment: can you give us an idea of what an "minor" variation is and what a major variation is -- hard to guess this if we don't have a sense for the data.

Comment: @scsimon : done!
Hogan : the threshold of variation is 10% ; I did not really make a distinction between minor or major. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. In SQL Server 2012 i'd use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` but since you are on 2008 we can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `CTE` and then limit on the variation.

```
declare @test table (idMetaData int, TimeStamp varchar(64), SampleNumber bigint, ChannelValue decimal(16,10))
insert into @test
values
(3,'0,5036500',12073,0.4573468975),
(3,'0,5037000',12074,0.4418814526),
(3,'0,5037500',12075,0.4109505628),
(3,'0,5038000',12076,0.4109505628),
(3,'0,5038500',12077,0.4264160077),
(3,'0,5038999',12078,0.4573468975),
(3,'0,5039499',12079,0.4573468975),
(3,'0,5039999',12080,0.4109505628),
(3,'0,5040500',12081,0.3336233382),
(3,'0,5041000',12082,0.2408306686),
(3,'0,5041500',12083,0.1789688889),
(3,'0,5042000',12084,0.1789688889)

--set the minimum variation you want to keep. Anything greate than this will be removed
declare @variation decimal(16,10) = 0.0000000010

--apply an order with row_number()
;with cte as(
    select 
        idMetaData
        ,TimeStamp
        ,SampleNumber
        ,ChannelValue
        ,row_number() over (partition by idMetadata order by SampleNumber) as RN
    from @test),

--self join to itself adding the next row as additional columns
cte2 as(
select
    c.*
    ,c2.TimeStamp as C2TimeStamp
    ,c2.SampleNumber as C2SampleNumber
    ,c2.ChannelValue as C2ChannelValue
from cte c
left join cte c2 on c2.rn = c.rn + 1)


--only return the results where the variation is met. Change the variation to see this in action
select 
    idMetaData
    ,TimeStamp
    ,SampleNumber
    ,ChannelValue
from 
    cte2
where
    ChannelValue - C2ChannelValue > @variation or C2ChannelValue is null
```

This doesn't take an "average" which would have to be a running average but what it allows you to do is to use a variance measurement to say that any consecutive measurements which only vary by `n` amount, treat as a single measurement. The higher the variance you choose, the more rows that will be "removed" or treated equally. It's a way to **cluster** your points in order to remove some noise without using something like [K-Means which is hard in SQL.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c3ef/dbc417847a6d0208de5017a949f0292c3ce4.pdf)

Comment: yes this is why I asked my prior comment -- you need an idea of what size to make variation

Comment: Hi scsimon, thanks a lot -- I'm on SQL Azure ! So I can use LEAD, LAG,...
Could you shine your light on those ? Gracias

Comment: @laurens I don't see how you can reduce the dataset by 10% arbitrarily without setting some other rules in place, especially in TSQL. For example. If you wanted to remove 10% of the rows... which would you choose even if you looked at the average? You'd have to compute the average of every row for a N number of subsets to find the deviation. This is something for R, Python, etc... LEAD and LAG would do something similar to the above but you could average 2,3,4 or N number of previous rows.

Comment: @scsimon : the data has mostly the same built up, compare it to a Gauss curve. I want to play with my data using NTILE, AVG, LEAD, etc. until I have around 10% left of the rows I used to have. I only want some minor logic to not 'lose' the peek values when for example simply taking an average per 10 rows... your peek value will be evaporated. 
I'm not looking for very complex outbreaks in R, Python...
I hope this makes it a little more clear now, If you could 'pimp' your query with the newer functions LEAD, LAG,... it would be awesome. Kind regards

Comment: @laurens lead and lag just allows you to access the `n` row before or after the current row. This isn't wise in this situation because it's arbitrary and the values in between would be unknown. for example... if the row values were 1, 2, 3,100, 4, 5 and we used lead or lag to compare the previous 3rd row... we would miss the spike of 100. Thus, your results would be skewed. The code i have above i think is the best solution. You could run it again on the results of itself the first time to further reduce your rowcount without losing your spikes

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun.  I modified a stored procedure which generates dynamic stats for any table/query/measure.  This has been tailored to be stand-alone.

This will generate a series of analytical items for groups of 10 ... an arbitrary value.

Just a side note: If there is no true MODE, ModeR1 and ModeR2 will represent the series range.  When ModeR1 = ModeR2 then that would be the true mode.

**[dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=37cabfd921522f1b5571800d6220e5fc)**

**Example**

```
;with cteBase as (Select GroupBy = [idMetaData]
                        ,Item    = Row_Number() over (Partition By [idMetaData] Order By SampleNumber) / 10
                        ,RowNr   = Row_Number() over (Partition By [idMetaData] Order By SampleNumber) 
                        ,Measure = ChannelValue
                        ,TimeStamp
                        ,SampleNumber
                   From  @YourTable
                 ),
       cteMean as (Select GroupBy,Item,Mean=Avg(Measure),Rows=Count(*),MinRow=min(RowNr),MaxRow=max(RowNr) From cteBase Group By GroupBy,Item),
       cteMedn as (Select GroupBy,Item,MedRow1=ceiling(Rows/2.0),MedRow2=ceiling((Rows+1)/2.0) From cteMean),
       cteMode as (Select GroupBy,Item,Mode=Measure,ModeHits=count(*),ModeRowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By GroupBy,Item Order By Count(*) Desc) From cteBase Group By GroupBy,Item,Measure)

Select idMetaData    = A.GroupBy
      ,Bin           = A.Item+1       
      ,TimeStamp1    = min(TimeStamp)
      ,TimeStamp2    = max(TimeStamp)
      ,SampleNumber1 = min(SampleNumber)
      ,SampleNumber2 = max(SampleNumber)
      ,Records       = count(*)
      ,StartValue    = sum(case when RowNr=B.MinRow then Measure end)
      ,EndValue      = sum(case when RowNr=B.MaxRow then Measure end)
      ,UniqueVals    = count(Distinct A.Measure)
      ,MinVal        = min(A.Measure)
      ,MaxVal        = max(A.Measure)
      ,Mean          = max(B.Mean)
      ,Median        = isnull(Avg(IIF(RowNr between MedRow1 and MedRow2,Measure,null)),avg(A.Measure)) 
      ,ModeR1        = isnull(max(IIf(ModeHits>1,D.Mode,null)),min(A.Measure))
      ,ModeR2        = isnull(max(IIf(ModeHits>1,D.Mode,null)),max(A.Measure))
      ,StdDev        = Stdev(A.Measure)
 From  cteBase A
 Join  cteMean B on (A.GroupBy=B.GroupBy and A.Item=B.Item)
 Join  cteMedn C on (A.GroupBy=C.GroupBy and A.Item=C.Item)
 Join  cteMode D on (A.GroupBy=D.GroupBy and A.Item=D.Item and ModeRowNr=1)
 Group By A.GroupBy,A.Item
 Order By A.GroupBy,A.Item
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: John, ...wow, I'm looking into it now. Thanks a lot for your response

Comment: @laurens Hope it helps.  As I mentioned, the base was a dynamic sp I created some time ago to create dynamic stats from any source.  You will gain sigificant compression, with the added benefits of StartVal, EndVal, Mean, Median, Mode, and STDev.  Perhaps overkill, but you can eliminate what you don't need.  FULL DISCLOSURE:  I have run this process on 500K records, but never MILLIONS.

Comment: I used the above query but it is very very slow on 80k records (on Azure SQL S3) I fear I wont be able to use it for 250M rows! If you have other ideas, be my most welcome guest. Thanks anyways

Comment: @laurens Huh, well that's embarrassing, I just ran a test on 74,811 rows and return results in 0.467 seconds on my laptop.  My only thought would be to add a WHERE in cteBase, but I suspect you alread did.

Comment: I made a dedicated table with 80k rows (few columns), replace @yourtable by my tablename, run the query but had to cancel it after 7 mins running. Tried it a second time meanwhile, same result. Some of the functions which is poorly performing on SQL Azure maybe ?

Comment: @laurens Just for fun, I took your dataset of 163 records, and expanded it to 163,000 records via a cross join.  Returned results 1.928 seconds while the original 163 records returned results in 0.250 seconds

Comment: @laurens Dramatic improvements if you remove cteMedian and cteMode (and associated fields in the final select)